# OpenBSD - How to set static IP?

Tags: networking, openbsd, ifconfig

**Question**: How to set static IP in OpenBSD/LibertyBSD?

**Backstory**: I recently purchased a *BSD VPS and have been having some issues with networking. How do I set the IP address?

Comment: Did you check the OpenBSD docs at https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq6.html ? AFAIK there's a pretty good explanation.

Answer (score 3):

If your network device is `en0`, and you want to configure it with the persistent static IP address `10.1.2.3` and the netmask `255.255.255.0`, then you create `/etc/hostname.en0` with the contents

```
inet 10.1.2.3 255.255.255.0
```

This will take effect upon rebooting (when `/etc/netstart` is run; see [`netstart(8)`](https://man.openbsd.org/netstart)).

See also the [`hostname.if(5)`](https://man.openbsd.org/hostname.if) manual, and the networking section of the [OpenBSD FAQ](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq6.html).

Comment: What if it is not `en0`? I believe I selected `vio0` as the network interface during installation. </br> Also, do I need `root` access to edit `etc/hostname.en0`?

Comment: @WildForest33349 Then you simply use `vio0` in place of `en0` in my answer. You have to be root to make changes like these, yes.  I'm not aware of any Unix that allows you to change network configuration without root access.  The system installation process should have created `/etc/hostname.vio0` already (if not, you may just create it), so you just need to change its contents.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall properly try using [`ifconfig`](https://man.openbsd.org/ifconfig):

`# ifconfig [network interface] inet [address] netmask [netmask]`

You will need `root` so execute `su -` first.

---

---

To follow @[Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/542155/373757)'s post if the address is `10.1.2.3` and the netmask `255.255.255.0` on the network interface `vio0` you should be able to execute the following:

`# ifconfig vio0 inet 10.1.2.3 netmask 255.255.255.0`